# Reading a file into memory

Tags: c, file

Can you review below code for performance and stability considerations? It is supposed to take a filename or `NULL`. If it is a filename, read given file into memory. If it is `NULL`, read from `stdin` into memory.

```
struct file_data {
    char *data;
    size_t numChars;
};

/* Read whole file into memory */
struct file_data read_file(char *filename) {
    FILE *f;
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *data = NULL;
    size_t current_size = 0;
    size_t totalChars = 0;
    size_t nchars;

    if(filename) {
        f = fopen(filename, "r");
    } else {
        f = stdin;
    }

    do {
        data = (char *)realloc(data, current_size + BUFFER_SIZE);
        assert(data);
        current_size+=BUFFER_SIZE;
        nchars = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE, f);
        memcpy(&data[totalChars], buffer, nchars);
        totalChars+=nchars;
    } while(nchars == BUFFER_SIZE);

    struct file_data fd = {data, totalChars};
    return fd;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Check return values

You're not making sure `fopen` isn't failing when opening a file:

```
f = fopen(filename, "r");
```

Also check the return value of `fread` for failure:

> The total number of elements successfully read is returned. If this
>   number differs from the count parameter, either a reading error
>   occurred or the end-of-file was reached while reading. In both cases,
>   the proper indicator is set, which can be checked with ferror and
>   feof, respectively. If either size or count is zero, the function
>   returns zero and both the stream state and the content pointed by ptr
>   remain unchanged. size_t is an unsigned integral type.

## const parameters

The function should never modify the contents of the string `filename`, so declaring the parameter `const char *filename` is good practice.

## How does read_file signal a failure

You're asserting on realloc failure. I usually prefer returning gracefully even on *alloc* failures and leave it open to the caller to be able to cope and at least shutdown nicely. But that is not necessary in all cases.

However, touching the same area is how the `read_file` function signals a failure to it's caller? One way would be:

```
struct file_data fd = {NULL, 0};
return fd;
```

Or changing the function to:

```
int read_file(const char *filename, struct file_data *fd)
{
     assert(fd);
     ...
     fd->data = data;
     fd->numChars = totalChars;
     return 0; // On success.
     ...
     return -1; // On failure.
}
```

## Read directly into the data buffer

You're doing unnecessary copying by using `memcpy` and a separate temporary `buffer` to read the file contents into.

How you could read it into the `data` buffer directly instead (getting rid of `buffer`):

```
size_t offset = 0;
nchars = fread(&data[offset], 1, BUFFER_SIZE, f);
// TODO: Remember to check nchars for error condition.
offset += nchars;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read the entire contents of a file into a buffer in memory, then the best way to do it is to map the file into memory, using [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) on Unix, or [`CreateFileMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537.aspx) and [`MapViewOfFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366761.aspx) on Windows. This has a bunch of advantages over the approach in the post:

1. It's fast: the memory copy (in the `fread`) is avoided.
2. It's lazy: the memory gets mapped as soon as `mmap` returns, but does not necessarily get read from disk until the process actually touches the memory. So if your program doesn't use the whole file, then only the parts it does use are loaded.
3. The mapping operation succeeds or fails as a whole: you don't have to deal with error cases in which you've loaded part of the file into memory.

The downsides of memory-mapped I/O are:

1. It's not portable.
2. It only works on disk files (not on sockets, pipes, terminals, etc) and so it's less general than standard I/O.

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with the line

```
    data = (char *)realloc(data, current_size + BUFFER_SIZE);
```

The problem is that this `realloc()`s each time through the loop, increasing by `BUFFER_SIZE` each time. It would be more efficient for each `realloc()` double the size of `data`, and only do so when necessary, instead of each time through the loop.